# Settings > IDE settings > Resources disappeared?

Tags: intellij-idea

I just upgraded from Intellij 11 to 12 and after the upgrade, the "resources" submenu disappeared.

I have to manually add some taglib uri's through that screen and now I can't code decently anymore because all of my jsp pages are completely red. Did it change location in IDEA12? The search function doesn't show anything...

Comment: `Settings` | `Schemas and DTDs`.